# No internet access for system services; however, browser access works

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, apt, internet

Unable to reload repos via apt-get, aptitude, or synaptic. Dropbox does not connect or sync. Pithos does not connect to pandora.com. Chrome and Firefox browsers do work fine.

I have been unable to find why my browsers can touch the internet and not any other apps can.

Comment: Do you have any proxy in your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that every port on your network is blocked, except 80 that us used for browsing.

You should elaborate more about your network environment - we have too small amount of information to help you.

On first hand, you should contact your network administrator if you know that there is one.

Comment: It took a while for me to find it. I found that i had an application called Anon-proxy mis-configured. After running "apt-get remove anon-proxy & rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/lock", and a restart. Than everything worked. While I didn't give enough info in my question, your response still helped me. thanks.